# How can I fix java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError?

Tags: java, exception

I am writing a game and am now in the last phrase. I am going to write the load class but when I press the load button, I get an exception, which is caused by a null pointer.

However, I allocated every object and arrays with `new`. Moreover, I have points that are non-`static` but are `volatile`.

This is my code:

```
class LOADSTATE 
{
    private char[] mapx;
    int x=0, y=0;

    public LOADSTATE()throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        String line;
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            GamePlay.tm[i].start();
        }
    }
    GamePlay.t.start();
    int flag=0;
    int m=0;
    BufferedReader fr=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("save.txt"));
    while((line=fr.readLine())!=null){
        if(flag==0){
            GamePlay.me.name=line;
        }
        if (flag==1){
            GamePlay.tt.time=Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        else if(flag==2){
            GamePlay.lvl=Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        else if(flag==3){
            GamePlay.win=Boolean.parseBoolean(line);
        }
        else if(flag==4){
            GamePlay.mainlvl=Boolean.parseBoolean(line);
        }
        else if(flag==5){
            GamePlay.lvl1=Boolean.parseBoolean(line);
        }
        else if(flag==6){
            GamePlay.lvl2=Boolean.parseBoolean(line);
        }
        else if(flag==7){

            GamePlay.lvl3=Boolean.parseBoolean(line);
        }
        else if(flag>7&&flag<37){
            if(flag%3==2){
                x=Integer.parseInt(line);
            }
            if(flag%3==0){
                y=Integer.parseInt(line);
                GamePlay.monster[m].oldPos.setLocation(x, y);
            }
            if(flag%3==1){
               GamePlay.monster[m].existance=Boolean.parseBoolean(line);
                m++;
            }
        }
        else if(flag==37){
            x=Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        else if(flag==38){
            y=Integer.parseInt(line);
            GamePlay.me.oldPos.setLocation(x, y);
        }
        else if(flag==39){
            GamePlay.me.killed=Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        else if(flag==40){
            GamePlay.me.health=Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        else if(flag>40){
            mapx=line.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0;i<map.length;i++){
                map[flag-41][i]=Integer.parseInt(""+mapx[i]);
            }
        }
        flag++;
    }
    fr.close();
  }
}






class GamePlay extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
static boolean lvl1=true;
static boolean lvl2=false;
static boolean lvl3=false;
static boolean mainlvl=false;
static Me me=new Me();
static Portal portal=new Portal();
static Shot shot=new Shot();
static Thread s;
static KeyBoard keyBoard=new KeyBoard();
static Monster monster[]=new Monster[10];
static boolean win;
static Thread tm[]=new Thread[10];
static int score=1000;
static timeThread tt=new timeThread();
static Thread t=new Thread(tt);
static int time=0;
JButton btn=new JButton("start");
JButton btn1=new JButton("stop");
JButton btn2=new JButton("fixer");
JLabel lbl=new JLabel("time :");
JLabel lbl1=new JLabel("score :");
JLabel lbl2=new JLabel("health :");
JLabel lbl3=new JLabel("assasins :");
/**/}
```

I call game play before load state.

Comment: Can you provide the error log and show where exactly does the exception arise

Comment: Please show the full stack trace - and fix up the formatting of your code. (Do you really need that many static variables? That's a big code smell...)

Comment: There is missing code. At "GamePlay.t.start();" there is no method.